# Please suggest ways to reduce the computational time of the below code

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
ax = matplotlib.pyplot.axes(projection='3d')
for i in range(255):
     for z in range(255):
          for a in range(255):
               ax.plot3D(i,z,a,'black')
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

I am trying to make a cube of black color using matplotlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a [`meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

i,a,z = np.meshgrid(*[np.arange(0, 255, 20)]*3)
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(i, a, z)
```

*NB. I only plotted a fraction of the points here for clarity*

[image: matplotlib scatter]